# Network Vis.js node with description

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm using  vis.js to draw the graph (nodes + edges) and I want to add some description below each node (picture). 
Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ppz5rur/1/), you can use the `title` attribute.
Click on node 1 to see it working.

```
{id: 1, label: 'Node 1', title: 'test'}
```

You can find more documentation about how to use the edges [here](http://visjs.org/docs/network/edges.html).

Comment: actually, they are asking about a different thing – a label that is below the node along with the main label. As far as I know, there's no out-of-box option to implement this